# Fluid simulation and animation

Tags: rendering, animation, blender-internal-render-engine, physics, fluid-simulation

https://www.instagram.com/p/Ba0fhHGAXxn/?taken-by=dkpatel25

As seen in above video I made the man using "control" property from Fluid simulation.
How can I make the man walk or animate in any kind with the fluid still inside him???

Comment: Have you tried just animating the mesh as you would any mesh? Providing it doesn't move too rapidly the fluid should simply be drawn along with the animated mesh.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually animate the object, and the fluid should stay with the object. You should increase the strength of the control factor while it moves to make sure the fluid doesn't slip away.